# Installing a new electrical panel in RV

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I just purchased [this breaker box from Home Depot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKnfS.jpg).  I'll be installing it in my RV.  Current will be supplied by a 12VDC to 120VAC, 3000W inverter.  I'll be using Single-Pole Type BR breakers.

Here's a picture of the box:

[image]

My current understanding is that I must install a grounding bar to the box.  This is my current understanding of how to connect the breaker to the main supply.:

[image]

Here is my understanding of how I would wire in new circuits:

[image]

Does this look right?  I would really appreciate your help -- I've been beating myself over the head about this.

Comment: Also, this does "look right", but I'm not sure what other considerations you have with an inverter or being installed in an RV.

Comment: VTC because this is word for word identical to another question which has good, in-depth, more-than-one-line answers.  Sorry Seth.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this looks right!  Great pictures!

Comment: This is for an RV tho - where is a grounding rod coming into play?

Comment: That is true, I edited it.  I was figuring it was stationary.